# Mapping Json data to dropdown in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a response data from api call and I want to map the response.data to a dropdown list. The response.data is an array:

```
 [{value: value1, name: name1}, 
 {value: value2, name: name2}
 ]
```

How to use the map() function to form a dataList has both value and name pair?  Thanks.

```
 const dataArray= response.data;
 const dataList = [...new Set(dataArray.map(item => item.name))];
```

where to add item.value above?

I want to do something like below:
     {this.state.dataList.map((item,indx)=>{item.name})}

Comment: I did this const dataList = [...new Set(dataArray.map(item => item))]; to get both value and name for the dropdown but it causes duplicated dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by using const unique = [...new Map(arr.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()]